# Run Magento 2 On low end system resources,

Tags: magento2, installation, development, system-configuration

I saw a system with below configuration :-

- dual core processor
- 8 gb ddr3 Ram
- 240 gb SSD
- windows 10

**I've tried to run Magento 2 in it using Bitnami stack, but its very slow.**

**Is their any other way or Virtual system available to install magento in it & use it for development ?**

A little better speed would be better then very slow speed.

Feel free to share thoughts.

Thankyou

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this is not an ans it just a suggestion which you can try**

instead of windows 10 you can use linux (ubuntu) which will be enough to handle magento or there is another thing but i am not very familiar with its called Docker it basically creates an environment for magento 2 just like linux just give it a try:-

i am sharing a link that may be helpful for you just try it and if you face any issues then kindly post another question and add docker in keyword may be someone will solve you queries.

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/165161-magento2-docker-on-windows

Comment: I support this answer. I ran a mini Ubuntu OS through hyper V on windows. On Ubuntu I ran docker. Still performed a lot better than native docker for windows. Eventually made the full switch. Now work on Debian. Home and at work.

Comment: Thanks @DominicXigen am not familiar with docker installation if you can help him with an ans to install it that would be really great help

Comment: Thanks @Pramod , yes Dominic you'd like to add answer ?

Comment: Dominic Xigen what are your system configuration ?

Comment: i have mentioned configuration of the system, could you suggest what software i can use to make
magento 2 development environment ?

Comment: i think you should go with linux some light ones like linux mint

Comment: @Pramod will it help with development with m2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used `aws` for some time and seem to have a working solution that has many benefits.

- I use a micro instance (so really tiny). Yet, I have magento 2 with sample data on it. It is not very fast but it is faster from what I had with a mac 16Gb RAM previously.
- This solution is very good value for money. I only switch on the instance when I work on it. I keep the firewall open only to my IP so that I am the only one using the site (that ensures it is fast)
- If I need to run my site faster for 1 week or less. I can create an image and run this image on a bigger instance.

Overall, this way of working costs less than buying a new machine but is quite flexible and has many benefits along the one mentioned above. Overtime a new machine gets deprecated whereas this method always uses what is good on the market