# Which Magento version is best for windows local development?

Tags: magento2, installation, development

This might sound subjective but I can't help but to post it here in the Stack.

I was really struggling with Magento 2 installation setup.

I am trying to setup a Magento 2 local windows dev environment using some of the latest Magento versions, I used composer version 1.10.x, attempted to install versions starting from 2.3.6 to 2.4.1, but none of them work.

I got stuck. I have done all the best possible options but none of them seem to work in my desktop machine using Windows 10. All I got was bunch of installation errors.

Currently, I am trying to setup a VM using virtualbox with Ubuntu. I hope this will make things easier.

Comment: VM using virtualbox - is is done ? Can you share your system config ?

Comment: not yet, still on going setup

Comment: Ok please update how is the performance after setup magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento2 version from 2.2.7 to 2.2.9 in windows 10. I am already using 2.2.7 since around 1 year and it works fine. Sometimes, it requires to delete generated folder after compilation. Otherwise it works fine.

Please let me know if you need any further help!

Thanks..

Comment: Could you please share your thoughts on this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326757/run-magento-2-on-low-end-system-resources ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows development for Magento 2 is not supported by Magento. The only operating systems that are supported are linux based.

Magento specifies the file path separator it uses and it causes issues. You can get around this by using WSL I believe.

It's usually better to run it on a supported operating system, which would be closer to your server environment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link to do the installation on windows 10/xammp.

https://ccbill.com/kb/install-magento-windows

It works but the performance is not good.

Magento is very temperamental, you have to follow the tutorial very precisely

The version number of php, mysql or elasticsearch, must be respected according to the version of magento you want to install.

Sources :
[MagentoSystemRequirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)